# Add Dynamic Flex Tables with unique names in Java GWT

Tags: gwt, dynamic, flextable

I need to create dynamic flex tables with unique names.

Consider this example,

```
FlexTable ft1= new FlexTable();
FlexTable ft2= new FlexTable();
FlexTable ft3= new FlexTable();
FlexTable ft4= new FlexTable();
```

I want each flex table to be created with a unique name.How can this be done dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Options for each of your widgets:

```
ft1.getElement().setId("id1");
ft1.getElement().setPropertyString("name", "name1");
ft1.getElement().setAttribute("name", "name1");
```